# This is about half wave rectifier circuit

Tags: rectifier

[image]

1. Why is there a huge percentage error difference in ripple voltage comparing experiment and calculation (red) and 12.9 % comparing experiment and simulation (green)?
2. Why is there an increase in input voltage from 30 to 30.8 V (2.6 % increase) when there is no connection change to the power supply for the two sets of experiments?

Comment: Because capacitors have a tolerance of +-20% or more as standard practice.  Resistors have tolerances also.

Comment: As to your second question, I suspect it's because your signal source has a output impedance and you're viewing the "input voltage" after that impedance. The drop across that impedance will be larger in the 10uF case. If you add a source resistor into you simulation you may get a closer match to reality.

Comment: Welcome! Please post a schematic of your setup with component values.